# youtube video upload issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using [joedawson /
youtube](https://github.com/joedawson/youtube) laravel package. I have an issue with the video upload. I first upload the video to my project folder using below code:

```
if ($this->uploaded_video) {

        $filename = $this->uploaded_video->getFilename();
        $this->uploaded_video->storeAs('public/instruction-videos', $filename);
    }
```

It's uploaded successfully to project folder and i can access the video in browser by getting the url from below code

`$fullpath = asset('storage/instruction-videos/'.$filename);`

I can see the video in browser by accessing the path which I get from the above code snippet.

I upload the video to youtube using below code

`$video = Youtube::upload($fullpath, ['title'=> 'title','description' => 'description'],'unlisted');`

But I get the below error when I upload it to youtube
[image: Screenshot from 2022-08-17 18-12-44]

Comment: The filesize error is referencing a localhost URI (127.0.0.1). If this is online on your Youtube account then it's almost certainly a Youtube glitch and will probably be fixed shortly.

Comment: i am trying it from yesterday. i probably think it is not related to youtube glitch if i am not wrong.

Comment: `filesize` does not work for HTTP URLs, only for file system paths. Likely the upload script uses it to determine with `Content-Length` header to send. See to it that you pass a local filesystem path to `Youtube::upload`, and not an HTTP URL.

Comment: i have checked the local path as well. it show me the same error. let me try it again and i will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: `$fullpath = asset('storage/instruction-videos/'.$filename);` - the explicit purpose of `asset` is to create _URLs_. Wrong tool for the job here. You should probably be using `storage_path`

Comment: which path should i use than?

Comment: i have tried this one as well `$fullpath = storage_path('public/instruction-videos/'.$filename);` but it's giving the same error

Comment: THe URL starting with `127.0.0.1` indicates that the file has been "uploaded" to a "local" path rather than a remote server. So, your video file has not been uploaded remotely and this is why Youtube can not load it. I do not know how laravel operates but I would suggest checking that your Laravel install has a correctly configured ***remote*** server to send the files to. Your browser will still load the video file because the browser is on your local machine so can access local files.

Answer (score 0):

Please enter path as a local path, not an http path.

```
$fullpath = '/var/www/html/project/storage/instruction-videos/ ~~~'
```

in the form

Comment: The filepath mentioned in the question looks like a *relative* local path.